# Prove a transformation is a variational symmetry for J

Tags: transformation, calculus-of-variations, symmetry, invariance

The following problem is from The Calculus of Variations by B.von Brunt (page 215, Exercise 9.2.1)

Let
$$
J(y)=\int_a^b xy'^2\mathrm{d}x.
$$

Show that the transformation
$$
X=x+\epsilon2x\ \mathrm{ln}x,\ \ Y=(1+\epsilon)y
$$
is a variational symmetry for $J$.

**My Attempt:**
I know to be a variational symmetry we require;
$$
J(Y)=\int_{X(a)}^{Y(b)}X\dot{Y}^2\mathrm{d}X=J(y)=\int_a^b xy'^2\mathrm{d}x.
$$
where $\dot{Y}=\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}X}$

ie. The transformation does nothing to the value of the integral.

It has been proven that both $X$ and $Y$ have inverse functions. Hence,
\begin{align}
Y(X)&=(1+\epsilon)y(x(X))\\
\dot{Y}(X)&=(1+\epsilon)\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dX}
\end{align}
also,
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dX}&=\frac{1}{1+2\epsilon(\ln{x}+1)}
\end{align}
but when I plug all this in I do not get the required equivalence. What am I doing wrong?

Any help/guidance would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of "variational symmetry"?

Comment: @gerw It is a Variational symmetry if once the transformation has taken place the integral is left unchanged. ie. J(y)=J(Y)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have

$$
\frac{dY}{dX} = \frac{dY/dx}{dX/dx} 
= \frac{d((1+\epsilon)y)/dx}{d(x+\epsilon 2x \ln(x))/dx}
= \frac{(1+\epsilon)\dot{y}}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)}
$$

so

$$
\int^{Y(b)}_{X(a)} X \dot{Y}^2 dX = \int_a^b (x+\epsilon 2x \ln(x))
\left(\frac{(1+\epsilon)\dot{y}}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)}\right)^2 \frac{dX}{dx}dx
$$

$$
= \int_a^b x \frac{(1+\epsilon 2 \ln(x))(1+\epsilon)^2}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)}\dot{y}^2dx
$$

Now since the term
$$
\frac{(1+\epsilon 2 \ln(x))(1+\epsilon)^2}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)} =
\frac{(1+\epsilon 2 \ln(x))(1+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)}
$$
$$
= \frac{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)}{1+2\epsilon + 2\epsilon\ln(x)} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
$$

Then looking at the Theorem as stated in [this book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=L4MKxr41900C&lpg=PA143&dq=calculus%20of%20variations%20noether%27s%20theorem&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q=calculus%20of%20variations%20noether%27s%20theorem&f=false) it follows that
the functional is variational invariant under the transformation.